# Doctrine Class "..\.." has no association named "..."

Tags: orm, doctrine, relation

I hope you can help me with this problem because I really cannot see what is wrong here.

I have 2 entities: **RokZaPrijavuProjekta** AND **Predmet**.

**RokZaPrijavuProjekta:**

```
/**
* @ORM\Table(name="rok_prijava_projekta")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="JP\AdminBundle\Repository\RokZaPrijavuProjektaRepository")
*/
class RokZaPrijavuProjekta
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var integer $id_predmet
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Predmet")
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_predmet", type="integer")
 */
private $predmet;

/**
 * @var date $od
 * @ORM\Column(name="od", type="date")
 */
private $od;

/**
 * @var date $do
 * @ORM\Column(name="do", type="date")
 */
private $do;

/**
 * @var string $info
 * @ORM\Column(name="info", type="string", length=120)
 */
private $info;
}
```

**Predmet entity code:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="predmeti")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="JP\AdminBundle\Repository\PredmetRepository")
 */
class Predmet
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string $sifra
 * @ORM\Column(name="sifra", type="string", length=64)
 */
private $sifra;

/**
 * @var boolean $vidljiv
 * @ORM\Column(name="vidljiv", type="boolean")
 */
private $vidljiv;
}
```

**Repository method:**

```
$q = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
->select('rzpp')
->where('rzpp.predmet = :predmet')
->from('JPAdminBundle:RokZaPrijavuProjekta', 'rzpp')
->leftJoin("rzpp.predmet", "p")
->setParameter('predmet', $predmet)
->getQuery();
```

Both getters and setters for all class members are defined properly.

Now, "RokZaPrijavuProjekta" has a foreign-key reference to "Predmet", so many of these "RokZaPrijavuProjekta" can have the same "Predmet".

I want to create unidirectional ManyToOne relation for this purpose but keep getting exception thrown:

> *Class JP\AdminBundle\Entity\RokZaPrijavuProjekta has no association named predmet*

I went all over [Doctrine documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html), but found that this is the preferred way to define unidirectional many-to-one relation.

Do you have any idea what might be a problem here?

---

### UPDATE

- Added Predmet entity code...
- Added Repository method

---

Thanks a lot!

Regards,
Jovan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you show Predmet entity code?

Or just try out this code:

```
// RokZaPrijavuProjekta
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Predmet", inversedBy="rokzaprojects")
 */
protected $predmet;


//Predmet
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RokZaPrijavuProjekta", mappedBy="predmet")
 */
protected $rokzaprojects;
```

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot to include "Predmet" entity code before, so I edited my post. 
By specifying "inversedBy" and "mappedBy" wouldn't that be bidirectional relation?

Comment: Hey Inori, I have tried putting bidirectional relation like you suggested but it still does not work. :( Maybe it has something to do with my repository method code? I have edited my post again to include it as well... Thanks!

Comment: Inori, I can't really say what was the problem but now it's gone. I literally copy/pasted your code and this time it worked. 
Site-note: while running 
`app\console doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql` 
on a separate entity manager, I noticed that foreign key was not being created between these 2 tables. Probably was some typo (but not sure which one).... :-/

Anyhow... thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Haha, glad I could help(?) I guess :D

Answer (score 30):

Well, last night I encountered the same problem again. This time I took some time to figure out why it started working so suddenly last time (at the time of my question above).

So, the bottom line and **solution** to the problem:

In my entity class I had both `@Column` and `@ManyToOne` annotation where I used `@Column` to define name of column in database and `@ManyToOne` to define relation. The point is that you need to **remove** `@Column` annotation and replace it with `@JoinColumn` thus defining both `name` and `referencedColumnName` attributes. Check these snippets out:

### This will not work:

(either with or without `@JoinColumn`)

```
/**
 * @var integer $file
 * @ORM\Column("name="id_file", type="integer")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="File")
 */
private $file
```

### But this **will**:

```
/**
 * @var integer $file
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="File")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_file", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $file
```

I hope this will be helpful to someone...

Cheers!

Comment: hey jperovic, just wanted to say thanks for putting the solution up. You probably just saved me an hours worth of scratching my head :D

Comment: Thank you jperovic, two years later and the solution is still helping people out. Been going round in circles until I found this.

Comment: @AMP Glad I could have in any way ;)

Comment: don't know what to do with same error until i find your explaination, you deserve even more credit Mr Perovic!

Answer (score 2):

Additional Info, the format of the comments **does matter**

I wasted a few hours just to find out that i missed a asterisk sign in the comments

This won't work

```
/*
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Custom\Models\ProductText", mappedBy="product", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist","remove"})
 */
protected $texts;
```

however this works

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Custom\Models\ProductText", mappedBy="product", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist","remove"})
 */
protected $texts;
```

notice the missing asterisk (*) at the first line of the first example

Comment: I know that I shouldn't leave comments just for "thanks". But damn this cost me hours upon hours to find. Thank you very much.